# Jackson @JsonValue is conflicting with @JsonTypeInfo; How to make them work together

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson2

I am using the `Jackson` for serialization of a `POJO`. This `POJO` class consists of some fields and a `Map<String,Object> others`. I am using the `Custom Serializer` while writing `JSON` for this `MAP` field. I want to avoid getting the `Map field name "others"´ in my` JSON`. Hence, I am using the` @JsonValue`on the`Map`field but using the`@JsonValue`is conflicting with`@JsonTypeInfo`. I need both annotations in my class how can I achieve this?

As of now, I am getting the `JSON` as following: (With both `@JsonValue` and `@JsonTypeInfo`)

```
[ "Customer", {
  "name" : "Rise Against",
  "google:sub" : "MyValue-1",
  "age" : "2000"
} ]
```

I would like to get the `JSON` as following with both `@JsonValue` and `@JsonTypeInfo`: (As you can see the `others` key is committed but its values are added to the JSON directly)

```
{
  "isA" : "Customer",
  "name" : "Batman",
  "google:sub" : "MyValue-1",
  "age" : "2008"
}
```

I am able to get the output but I need to remove the annotation from my class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
```

But if I remove this then I will not get the `isA` property in my JSON. I want to know how to make the `Jackson Json Serializer` work both with the `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonValue`.

Output without `@JsonTypeInfo` but with `@JsonValue`:

```
{
  "name" : "Rise Against",
  "google:sub" : "MyValue-1",
  "age" : "2000"
}
```

Output without `@JsonValue` but with `@JsonTypeInfo`

```
{
  "isA" : "Customer",
  "name" : "",
  "age" : "",
  "others" : {
    "name" : "Rise Against",
    "google:sub" : "MyValue-1",
    "age" : "2000"
  }
}
```

Following is my `Customer` class Pojo:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "others"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreType
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
public class Customer {

  @XmlElement(name = "name", required = true)
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "age", required = true)
  private String age;

  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomExtensionsSerializer.class)
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  @XmlPath(".")
  @JsonValue
  private Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setOthers(String key, Object value) {
    others.put(key, value);
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getOthers() {
    return others;
  }
}
```

Following is my `Custom serializer:

```
public class CustomExtensionsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {

  private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public void serialize(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    recusiveSerializer(value, gen, serializers);
    gen.writeEndObject();
  }

  public void recusiveSerializer(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> extension : value.entrySet()) {
      if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        //If instance is MAP then call the recursive method
        recusiveSerializer((Map) extension.getValue(), gen, serializers);
      } else if (extension.getValue() instanceof String) {
        //If instance is String directly add it to the JSON
        gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) extension.getValue());
      } else if (extension.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) {
        //If instance if ArrayList then loop over it and add it to the JSON after calling recursive method
        gen.writeFieldName(extension.getKey());
        gen.writeStartObject();
        for (Object dupItems : (ArrayList<String>) extension.getValue()) {
          if (dupItems instanceof Map) {
            recusiveSerializer((Map) dupItems, gen, serializers);
          } else {
            gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) extension.getValue());
          }
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `@JsonTypeInfo.include` to `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY`

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking your time and responding. I have actually tried this. Adding this will produce the same JSON as in the first JSON provided in the question. It adds the `Array` as a wrapper to my JSON and also, values are completely messed up something like this: `[ "Customer", {
  "google:main" : {
    "google:sub" : "MyValue-1"
  },
  "name" : "BATMAN",
  "age" : "2008"
} ]`